# listing all contents of a folder in tfs

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Given a particular path of folder in tfs, I need to recursively find all files and folders within the folder for a given changeset. In other words, i need to get the transitive closure of a path in tfs for a given changeset. The problem I'm facing in doing so is listing the contents of a particular folder within tfs..
How would this be possible in C# ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want 'folder contents as of changeset X' and not 'folder contents that were part of changeset X'

GetItems is the right call to use, just pass in a version spec for the changeset you're interested in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb138911.aspx

so, assuming you already have a reference to the VersionControlServer instance:

```
var myFolderAtChangeset17 = versionControlServer.GetItems("$/MyFolder", new ChangesetVersionSpec(17), RecursionType.Full);
```

If I misunderstood and you happen to want to 'folder contents that were part of changeset X', there's a few different ways of doing it, but getting the changeset with [GetChangeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb138627.aspx) and just filtering the [Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.changes.aspx) is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be more what you're looking for.  This gets all changes in a changeset and iterates through them, identifying the ones in the given path.  This could be shortened with a linq query, but I'm leaving it a bit more expanded to give the gist of what I'm trying to say:

```
    TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080");
    VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Changeset cs = vcs.GetChangeset(6284868);

    foreach (Change change in cs.Changes)
    {
        if (change.Item.ServerItem.StartsWith("$/Application Common/Dev/src"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Changeset {0}, file {1}, changes {2}",
                cs.ChangesetId, change.Item.ServerItem, change.ChangeType.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I don't need the items in a particular changeset. I need all files and folder under a given folder in tfs.

Comment: Then you can use GetItems()  ...  your question does mention changeset, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work..

```
    TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080");   
    VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService();   
    ItemSet items;

    items = vcs.GetItems(tfsPath, RecursionType.Full);
```

If you have any other ideas, please post them..

Comment: you code is missing the part where you define tfsPath to pass to GetItems

Answer (score -1):

You can use the changeset webservice to get an XML document that contains all of the changed items for a particular changeset.  Then just loop through the list of changed items and see if they are in the path you are looking for.

Here's the URL to the changeset webservice:

http://`your_tfs_server`/VersionControl/Changeset.aspx?artifactMoniker=`your_changeset_number`&webView=true

Comment: can I just do a VersionControlServer.getItems() and loop thro the derived array. I'm just trying it out now...

Comment: Downvoted (sorry David).  You should not use the webservice to do this under any (normal) circumstances.  These are internal and can change without notice.